TypeScript で 0 と 1 を比較すると「重複が無い」というエラーになる理由は？
console.log(0 == 1); を実行すると以下のエラーメッセージが表示されます。
This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types '0' and '1' have no overlap.

私は 0 と 1 はどちらもnumberなので型は同じであると思っていたのですが、エラー文によれば「0 と 1 は型の重複がない」と書いてあります。
なぜこのようなエラーが出るか教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

intとstringには特殊化した値そのものの型を作れます
また、リテラルにはそのような型が付きます
ここでは「1という型」と「0という型」に重複がない、と言われています
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types

In addition to the general types string and number, we can refer to specific strings and numbers in type positions.

のところです

ドキュメントにも例示がありますが、1や0を型として取り扱って
let a: 1 = 1;  //「1という型」の変数に1を代入
a = 0;  // これはエラー。「1という型」に0は代入できない

とか
let a: 1 | 0 = some_function();

if (a == 1) {
} else {
  // ここで a はnarrowingによって 0 で確定
}

とかできます（余談気味ですが）
